# New to Ubuntuserver, need help with server ip (nginx)

Tags: server, nginx, ip

I am completely new to nginx. I started with it to use my livestream on my gaming pc going through the nginx-server and push it to twitch. After many hours of trying to setting everything up, I think I've managed to do so.

My problem that remains, and I'm sure it's an easy problem, is that I can't find what my servers IP-adress is. I've been googled around how I can find it, and I've been looking inside the server block and the HTTP-block for it in the nginx config as well. I really can't find it tho.

Appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal of the server type in <s>ifconfig</s> "ip address". ON my setup it is the second line from the top of the response it spits out.

EDIT as Stephen C points out ifconfig is legacy, this is the old command. Thanks Stephen C!

Comment: Have an upvote, but Adam's been gone for a long time.

Comment: Probably `ip addr` is better.  On recent Ubuntu versions, `ifconfig` is not installed by default.  (It is the "old fashioned" way.)